# Maximum Dark Notes?

Tags: theatrhythm-final-fantasy

Is there a maximum amount of Dark Notes one can get? I don't seem to get any after #42 (I've already got some notes lvl 90+).

Also, is there any way to get an access point to simulate to get more through streetpass - kinda like people have been doing with Pokémon X/Y, making home routers to emulate nintendo pass zones?

Comment: Ok, I just found out that HomePass doc https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvvH5W4E2lIwdEFCUkxrM085ZGp0UkZlenp6SkJablE#gid=0 has an entry for Theatrhythm - all that's left here is the question about Dark Notes limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold up to 99 Dark Notes at one time. Once you hit that limit, you won't be able to collect any more Dark Notes until you delete some of your older ones.

Comment: yey! finally got enough rep (and paid attention to it) to upvote your answer =D thanks =)